# How does git filter-branch affect repos used as submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-filter-branch

I want to use `git filter-branch` to remove some large files from the commit history of a repository named `problems`. Does this cause any issues in my repository `thesis`, which uses the `problems` repository as a submodule?

Namely, does the force push required with `git filter-branch` necessitate any special action or consideration in the `thesis` repository?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "yes".  Filter-branch works by *copying* commits, to new-and-improved commits with different hash IDs.

If the copied repository is used as a submodule, the superproject repository contains commits that store the raw hash IDs of the submodule's commits.  Since the new-and-improved commits have *different* hash IDs, the superproject now holds the old (i.e., wrong) hash IDs, at least for any commits that got copied-and-replaced like this.

What this implies is that you must now replace any commits *in* the superproject that have, as their gitlink, the hash ID of a commit that was replaced by a new-and-improved commit in the submodule repository.  Doing this is nontrivial.

The filter-branch command can be told to keep a mapping from old to new hash IDs, using the `--state-branch` option.  (This option was new in Git 2.15.0.)  You'll need this state mapping.  It's not clear off-hand *how* to use it when running a filter-branch over the superproject, but you'll need a filter that finds commits that contain gitlinks that have old-commit entries and tell the superproject filter to replace those with updated gitlinks.

Comment: A possible proposed solution for this problem on the git folks mailing list: `Hash for a commit sourcetree beside to a commit hash`: https://lore.kernel.org/git/7910309440.20230212162759@inbox.ru/